# C# parsing multiple elements

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have below xml structure.

```
<Bd>
<Det AccNo="380619034" Zip="344000"></Det>
<Det AccNo="380619022" Zip="345000"></Det>
</Bd>
```

It's known that there are always 2  elements under `<Bd>` tag.

I am able to retrieve first element using below code;

```
string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);
var y = xdoc.Descendants("Bd");


foreach (var x in y) {

var AccNo = x.Element("Bd")?.Element("Det")?.Attribute("AccNo")?.Value;

}
```

However this code is only giving me first element. I want to get the second element as well but not able to do so. What am i missing?

Comment: You could use `y.Nodes()` instead of just `y` in your `foreach`

Comment: Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: You should use @Sajid answer, it is more complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Linq` without loop, like the follwing code :

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);
IEnumerable<string> accNoList = xDocument.Descendants("Bd")
    .Descendants()
    .Select(x => x.Attribute("AccNo").Value);
```

**demo**

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", accNoList));
```

**Outcome**

```
"380619034, 380619022"
```

For your code, you can change it to:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);
var y = xdoc.Descendants("Bd")
    .Descendants();

foreach (var x in y)
{
    var AccNo = x.Attribute("AccNo")?.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(AccNo);
}
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: How can i store the outcomes as AccNo1 and AccNo2 as string?

Comment: Either, declaring two variables or a `List<string>` and adding them.

Comment: let say var AccNo1 = x.Attribute("AccNo")?.Value; what would be the AccNo2?

Comment: for you code Convert ``y`` to list like:``var z = y.ToList()`` ``string accNo1 = z[0].Attribute("AccNo")?.Value;string accNo2 = z[1].Attribute("AccNo")?.Value;``for my code you can use : ``string accNo11 = accNoList.FirstOrDefault();string accNo12 = accNoList.LastOrDefault();``